# adding Expression Encoder player to existing silverlight application

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-encoder

Hy all,

Im developing small media application in Silverlight. But now I have problem with Smooth streaming technology.

I generate some pretty player in expression Encoder 4 pro. But I cant find way how that player add to my existing application. When I open the player solution in visual studio I see pretty player.

Then I build solution and get xap files.
I take every dll form it and add it to my existing application. Then I create this code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SmootStreamingExample.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:SSME="clr-mamespace:Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming;assembly=Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming"
xmlns:ExpressionPlayer="clr-namespace:ExpressionMediaPlayer;assembly=ExpressionPlayer"
xmlns:MPT="clr-namespace:MediaPlayerTemplate;assembly=MediaPlayerTemplate"
xmlns:MediaPlayer="clr-namespace:ExpressionMediaPlayer;assembly=MediaPlayer"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmootStreamingExample"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600" x:Name="UC">
```

When I build this application i can see default player. There is no my skin in this example archetype style of player. Can you help me. What I doing wrong?

I have too problem with media in player that cant play media. There is only black screen (no error appear). But when a create object:

```
<SSME:SmoothStreamingMediaElement Grid.Column="0" AutoPlay="True" x:Name="SmoothPlayer" Margin="0" SmoothStreamingSource="http://streams.smooth.vertigo.com/elephantsdream/Elephants_Dream_1024-h264-st-aac.ism/manifest" Grid.Row="0" />
```

everithings go fine.

Answer (score 1):

The look and feel isn't stored in the DLL files, but in the `Page.xaml` file. See [this tutorial for more details](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35229/Using-Expression-Encoder-2-Silverlight-2-Templates-in-your-project.aspx?display=Print).